# Is there a way to display the names of every running session variable?

Tags: php, list, session, get

I would like to display every name of running session variable, so for demostration purposes, let's use this code as example:

```
<?php 

session_start();
$_SESSION['username'] = "any username";
$_SESSION['mail'] = 'any mail';
$_SESSION['example'] = 'just another session';

// GETTING THE NAMES OF THE "SESSIONS" AND SAVING THEM IN $sessionnames
echo $sessionnames;
```

The result should be something like this:

```
username
mail
example
```

I hope you can understand my example code,
thanks in advance.

Comment: Storing passwords in sessions, is *not* a good idea.

Comment: I know, it's just an example. Will update that.

Comment: You can to use this function to get only the keys : array_keys(); like this : array_keys($_SESSION);

Comment: It's worth reading through the various array functions to see what's available. https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php

Comment: @JaredFarrish Thanks for the help :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like that?

```
<?php 

session_start();
$_SESSION['username'] = "any username";
$_SESSION['mail'] = 'any mail';
$_SESSION['example'] = 'just another session';

// GETTING THE NAMES OF THE "SESSIONS" AND SAVING THEM IN $sessionnames

print_r($_SESSION);
echo '<br>';

foreach ($_SESSION as $key=>$value){
    echo $key.'<br>';
}    
?>
```